# Better way to put numbers side by side. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was a better approach to putting 2 numbers side by side without having to make them into a string.

For example:

if i have '2' and '3' and I wanted to '23' you would just concat them. But what if they were the number data type.

I was working with binaries and realized I don't actually know anyway to have

0101, and 1010 and put them together to create 01011010 without turning them into strings.

I know it's an odd question but I am just curious. Thanks again.

Comment: `(0b101 << 4 | 0b1010).toString(2).padStart(8, '0');`

Comment: For this kind of question you need to define what you mean by "better". Do you mean more performant? Or perhaps more maintainable and readable?

Comment: @IanNewson I guess I am looking for more performant. I would assume that more readable would be converting to a string and just concatenating. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method of doing it without string concatenation:

```
var values = [2,3];//Also works with arbitrary length arrays, e.g. [1,2,3,4,5]

var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
  var step = values[i] * (Math.pow(10, values.length - i) / 10);
  result += step;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ysd6exvw/

I've haven't benchmarked it for speed, and TBH I would suggest just using string concatenation instead of complicating the problem with this code.

EDIT:

Added a benchmark:

https://jsfiddle.net/4ap82rgq/

This shows that the string concatenation is fastest, although I did get one result where the above code was faster.